# Do I need two seperate Facebook applications for an iOS app and my site?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, titanium

I have a website that uses Facebook to authenticate users. I'm creating a mobile application that's tied to the site, and I want to offer a similar "connect to Facebook" functionality.  Do I need to create multiple Facebook applications, each with their own unique application id for the different "platforms"?

I've tried reading through the documentation, but I haven't found anything that guides me one way or the other. Would the same answer hold true for Twitter and / or [Foursquare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foursquare)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should create only one application if the applications are tied together on different platforms. You should not use different application ids due to these reasons:

1. You will have to take and store permissions differently for both applications. So a user who has approved your application on the web, will not be able to login to the application on iOS. There the user will have to approve it again.
2. Your users get distributed into different application ids, so your statistics suffer.
3. A Facebook application is best managed if it is single, as there are lots of things like Facebook policies to follow, `access_token` management, negative user feedback for your application.

Use one application id for:

- The ABCD game on web: `www.abcdExampleGame.com`
- the iOS application for the game: `abcdExampleGame`
- the Android application for the game: `abcdExampleGame`
- the [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) version of the game: `mobile.abcdExampleGame.com`